# Are "dev" packages supposed to have dependencies?

Tags: ubuntu, compile, packages

I'm using Ubuntu 16 LTS. I was trying to compile some stuff that requires llvm-3.9-dev, so I installed it. However, the project wouldn't build, saying it couldn't open `-lz`. I installed the zlib1g-dev package, and after that it built successfully. So my question is, if llvm-3.9-dev requires zlib1g-dev (by virtue of being built and packaged with LLVM_ENABLE_ZLIB=ON), shouldn't the llvm-3.9-dev package have a dependency on the zlibg1-dev package so it also gets installed? Or more generally, should dev packages depend on other dev packages that are needed to build against them? Is this a bug, or are users just expected to know how to fix this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Development packages (`-dev`) usually depend on other packages from same category if needed as library or pre-built binary if needed as tool or script.

But you need to verify if it is in: your source (not a bug), `llvm-3.9-dev` or other nested dependencies (bug for that specific package).

Use: `apt-rdepends llvm-3.9-dev` to get list of all dependencies recursively.